# Cuda: If I use only .x of block and threads, will it still use all available threads in GPU or for that using .y and .z of thread and block is a must?

Tags: memory, cuda

I have my program which requires maximum use of GPU.

So, does blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x; is able to access all the threads? or it is a must to use .y and .z also ?
is that mandatory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CUDA threads hierarchy is just a convenience abstraction and there's no requirement for using one, two or three dimensions, nor you will lose performances if you just use one dimension instead of all three of them. You will be able to use all the threads you launched with a set of indices as long as you specified the correct grid dimension.

> 2.2. Thread Hierarchy
>
> **For convenience**, threadIdx is a 3-component vector, so that threads can be identified using a one-dimensional, two-dimensional, or three-dimensional thread index, forming a one-dimensional, two-dimensional, or three-dimensional thread block. This provides a natural way to invoke computation across the elements in a domain such as a vector, matrix, or volume.

Read more at: http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#thread-hierarchy

Answer (score 0):

The way you get access to threads depends on the way you declare your grid and block dimensions. if it's a one dimensional grid and one dimensional block you can have access to all threads by only `.x`. That is arbitrary and program dependent. you can define your grid 1 or 2 dimensional and for blocks up to 3.